# checking if there is/are image(s) in a directory

Tags: javascript, typescript

imagine that there is a big Campus and it has more than 20 buildings. Each building has 1 or more photos. I keep all the photos in a folder in my Localhost and when i click the building it calls the directory and show the photos of the building.
My folder image is like: 12_1.jpg, 12_2.jpg,... where 12 is the building ID.

What i have done is :

```js
binaResim: Array<any> = [];

function checkImage(imageSrc, good, bad) {
        console.log("check image ",imageSrc);
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = good; 
        img.onerror = bad;
        img.src = imageSrc;
      };
```

```js
      let schoolPhoto = environment.resimUrl + data.attributes.bina_sira_no;
      this.binaResim=[];

      for (var k = 1; k < 100; k++) {
        var image=checkImage(schoolPhoto+ "_" + k +".jpg" ,
        function(){                     
         this.image= true;
          }, function(){
             this.image= false;
          });
             this.binaResim.push(schoolPhoto+ "_" + k + ".jpg" );

             if(!image){
                console.log("no anymore photo");
                break;
             }
       }
```

the problem is that each building may have different number of images, so I want to check the url inside "For loop" and break if there is no any directory.

In here the code runs but when a building has more than one photo, it only shows one image.

Comment: You should make this on serverside. Ajax request to get all photos in a folder would help you.

Comment: are you on server side or client side?

Comment: its client side.